# What does Bios do after Booting

Tags: io, boot, bios, rom

Does BIOS do something after booting? IO in BIOS mean input/output but isn`t bios used only when booting process? If BIOS is not used how can operating system interact with other hardware?

Comment: Why exactly do you ask? Please motivate your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read wikipage about [BIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS) & [booting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booting) & [firmware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firmware) & [UEFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface)

With current [operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) (in particular Linux, for which you'll find a big lot of documentation & resources; notice that Linux & [coreboot](http://www.coreboot.org/) is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), so you can study its source code), the BIOS is (nearly) only useful to load the boot loader (like GRUB), which later loads the Linux kernel.

In the 1980s, the BIOS was providing Basic Input Output Services (in 16 bits [real mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_mode)) to the [MS-DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS), hence its name. Today it is mostly legacy stuff.

The [Linux kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) has a lot of [device drivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_driver) interacting directly with the hardware devices (and do not need the BIOS for that)

<sup>NB: perhaps a tiny bit of some BIOSes are needed for [ACPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface), [SMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Mode#Entering_SMM), etc... Details are hardware and BIOS specific, and you should not care</sup>

See also http://osdev.org/

Comment: `the BIOS is (nearly) only useful to load the boot loader` But Why BIOS contains letters I and O which means Input/Output

Comment: For MSDOS legacy of 1980s

Comment: You can't imagine how legacy matters *heavily* on PCs. Aliens looking at that would find us completely crazy....

Comment: Why do you say ACPI is hardware or BIOS specific?