# Toy OS Filesystem

Tags: c, assembly, filesystems, kernel, osdev

I have developed a basic kernel in assembly/c that runs a basic terminal. I have set it up to run off of an iso with grub.

I would like to continue this OS, but without a file system, I feel as if there's really nothing else I could do. After much time on the internet, I have come up with really nothing I can do to implement this.

People have said implement FAT or make a VFS, but nothing any further, nor tutorials, nor any references to anywhere.

Could someone explain how a file system works, where I can get started/where I can connect a pre-made system, and how to use it?

Also, I do not have access to standard libraries when compiling my os. I use gcc, nasm, ld, and grub-mkrescue(for the disk image). I use qemu for emulation.

**EDIT to make less OT**

Can someone describe, in detail how a file system works, so when I look at the sources of file systems that have been implemented, like FAT, I can understand how to apply it to my own operating system?

**EDIT - Simpler**

Even easier. How could I directly access the hard drive? My kernel runs completely in protected mode, so could I switch out and write directly to the hard drive. A file system could be implemented with a file looking like this:

*name* ***special char*** *text* ***special char***

ie:

*hello world.script* ***0x00*** *println "Hello, world!!"* ***0x00***

Where you wouldn't need special segmentation, you would just look until you find the file name and the special character (something not in a string like '\0') and then read until you find the second non-string character.

Would there be a way to access the hard drive by switching in and out of protected mode or write a hard disk driver in order to implement this?

Comment: Sorry - Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: You found nothing about, for example, the FAT file system? What about [Design of the FAT file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_the_FAT_file_system)? That's just one of many links obtained with a Google search. Granted, there aren't tutorials that will give you a step-by-step how to code up the file system, but all the details you need about how different file systems are laid out exist with diagrams, etc.

Comment: The answer to your question of "how a file system works" depends upon the file system. There's lots of information if you Google "how does a file system work". Here's one article that may be helpful to start since it does explain some things in general with a bit of example: [Files Systems: FAT, NTFS, and HFS+](http://study.com/academy/lesson/files-systems-fat-ntfs-hfs-and-ffs.html). You can find similar articles that talk about Linux file systems (ext2, ext3, etc). Unfortunately, the question is still too broad to be on topic for this forum.

Comment: Is you OS [TernexOS2](http://blueokiris.webs.com/ternex-os-2-0)? You should have given the URL inside the question!

Comment: No. It's a different operating system for the x86 platform.

Comment: If you want your file system to be useful (e.g., allow files to be created, changed, and deleted when necessary), your simplistic scheme will break down. A file system is, among other things, a dynamic memory allocation scheme for a drive medium. Direct access of the hard drive could be through the BIOS, or you'd write your own device driver driver.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, read wikipage on [file systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) to have some broad view.

The relevant resource about [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) development is [OSdev](http://osdev.org/) (but perhaps your question is off-topic here). [Kernelnewbies](http://kernelnewbies.org/) could also help (explaining how Linux is doing). OSdev have wikipages explaining [FAT](http://wiki.osdev.org/FAT) & [Ext2](http://wiki.osdev.org/Ext2) in details.

You could design an OS without any files (but some other [persistence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_%28computer_science%29) machinery). See [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/285678/40065). You could have persistent processes (read also about [application checkpointing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing), [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29), [continuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation), [hibernation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernation_%28computing%29)).

But you should read some good books about Operating Systems (e.g. [by Tanenbaum](http://freecomputerbooks.com/Modern-Operating-Systems-by-Andrew-Tanenbaum.html), or the freely downloadable [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) book). Be fluent with some existing free software OS, e.g. Linux (& POSIX), so read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) (at least to understand many concepts and get a good terminology).

IMHO, the [FAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table) is such an ugly and inefficient file system that it is not worth looking into (except for legacy and compatibility reasons). [Ext4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) (see [here](http://kernelnewbies.org/Ext4)) should be better & the wikipage on [Ext2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext2) has a nice picture.

You could adapt some library providing a file system (e.g. [libext2](http://git.tyndur.org/?p=libext2.git;a=summary)) to your kernel.

You could perhaps adapt [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) to work on a raw disk partition.

You might have a notion of [*file*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_file) which is not like MSDOS (or Windows) or POSIX or `<stdio.h>`  files. For example, it might be a sequence of fixed size records (e.g. of 1Kbyte), not a stream of bytes.

You could organize your OS as a [microkernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microkernel) and have file systems given by application code.  Look into [VSTa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VSTa) and [HURD](https://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/hurd.html).

You need of course a disk driver, which fetches/writes blocks (of 4Kbytes) from your drive (disk I/O is always by blocks or [disk sectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_sector). Old small disks had 512 bytes blocks. New large disks have 4Kbytes ones, see [advanced format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Format)). It should be interrupt driven and uses [DMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access). You need a task [scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_%28computing%29). AFAIU, you [won't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31201991/841108) use the BIOS for this (perhaps the [UEFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface)); you need to understand how common hardware ([SATA](http://wiki.osdev.org/SATA) & [AHCI](http://wiki.osdev.org/AHCI)) works.

You should publish (*today!*) your toy OS as [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) (e.g. under [GPLv3](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html)+ on [github](http://github.com/)) to get feedbacks and contributions.

You might copy (if licenses are compatible) existing code from other [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) operating systems, and you certainly will study their source code to understand things.

So code some task scheduler, a [page fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault) handler, a [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), then add interrupt driven disk IO, and some file system code above that. Then you'll beginning to understand that an OS cannot be a *small* toy.... You might consider a microkernel or [exokernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exokernel) approach.

Comment: FAT is ugly and inefficient, but the OP is obviously a beginner and FAT is very simple in concept and design. So it may be a good starting point.

Comment: Then Ext2 is probably better, and better explained

Comment: OSDev is where you wanna go for OS dev. Has tons of articles on filesystems.

Comment: So far, it's not synced and pushed, but this is where the repository is: https://github.com/blueOkiris/Forward-OS

Comment: Could I, like the edit says, access the hard drive until I find the name? It's similar to the "file as fixed blocks" idea.

Comment: You really need to read a lot more material about operating system before coding your own. You are going nowhere if you don't understand much more about OSes in general!

Answer (score 4):

It would be simplest to use an existing open-source filesystem if the licence terms suit your needs. [ELM FatFs](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html) is one such library, with no usage restrictions whatsoever.  You only need to provide the device control interface layer using the provided stubs and examples.