# How to create a multistage bootloader with asm and c?

Tags: c, operating-system, nasm, qemu, bootloader

I want to create a simple 32-bit text-based operating system.

**Bootloader :**

Firstly I want to create a multistage bootloader.

Stage 1 :  Assembly code (NASM-Compiler)

Stage 2 :  C (GCC-Compiler)

**Kernel:**

Then it should load Kernel which should be written in C (GCC-Compiler)

I would also like to know how to properly compile and execute it.

**Emulator should be Qemu**

**A sample 32-bit Operating System that displays "Hello world" would be helpful.**

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to write an entire bootloader from scratch.  That's much too broad a question — the "answer" would involve someone writing most of one for you.  There's no simple "here's how to write a bootloader" in a few sentences or paragraphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't write your own bootloader. **Configure and use an existing bootloader, probably [GRUB](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/)**. This would make using your toy OS much easier (both for you and for other users).

Read http://osdev.org/ since they have a lot of resources about OS building on PCs (including a hello world OS).

Read also some good operating system book (e.g. [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)). You'll find out that there cannot be *very simple* OSes. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31301788/841108) answer.

Also, be at least quite fluent with POSIX and with Linux system programming (read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) at first).

Comment: OK, Thank you. Is there any 32-bit open source text-based operating system that i can experiment with ?

Comment: Linux is such an OS.... and [osdev](http://osdev.org/) has some links; BTW, I don't understand what you mean by text-based OS (since any POSIX system is text-based)

Comment: I was just looking for something like unix type operating system.              By the way, i just improvised my question. Kindly take a look at it.

Comment: Then, don't write a bootloader but focus your effort on your OS (and load it with GRUB)

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your answer.